# Python string formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm building up several command strings to pass to os.system. I want to group the common stuff into a string then add the specific stuff as needed. For example:

```
CMD = "python app.py %s -o %s > /dev/null"
option1 = "-i 192.169.0.1"
option2 = "results-file"
cmd = CMD, (option1, option2) #doesn't work
os.system(cmd)
```

I know cmd is a tuple. How do I get cmd to be the command string I want?

Comment: Just in case this is a real example, you should avoid concatenating strings to create shell commands for safety reasons. Use `subprocess.call` with a list of arguments. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @Joe. Good point. I am only using this in my unit tests of app.py so I guess it's okay for this.

Comment: @Joe Is that not only a problem if the strings are coming from outside.  If they are hardcoded like this what can go wrong?

Comment: Well, for starters, you might decide to take the string from outside in the future. Or you could make a mistake with the argument. It's just safest and best-practice. It's also a bit easier to read and saves you having to format strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `%` operator.

```
cmd = CMD % (option1, option2)
```

See also: [Python documentation on string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: You should use the format function.  `cmd= "python app.py {0:s} -o {1:s} > /dev/null".format( option1, option2 )`

Comment: @S.Lott Yes, `.format()` is definitely nicer. However, you don't need the ":s" in the format string -- "s" is the default type. So just "{0} -o {1}" is fine. But @Joe is right, subprocess is the way to go here!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way using the string `format()` method which processes [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
CMD = "python app.py {} -o {} > /dev/null"
option1 = "-i 192.169.0.1"
option2 = "results-file"
os.system(CMD.format(option1, option2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = CMD % (option1, option2)
```

This is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html).

Comment: yeah, but it only concatenated those strings, but you wanted to replace %s's by those option strings

Comment: Yes, appreciate that. I will give the prize to Sebastian P :-), but thanks anyway.